# Python method override rule

Tags: python, overriding

```
class a:
    def set(self, value):
        print value+1

    def set2(self, value):
        self.set(value)

class b(a):        
    def set(self, value):
        print value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = b()
    i.set2(10)
```

when executed, I got result as `10`, which means, `b.set()` was called, but why not `a.set()` since it was called with explict `self`?

P.S. 
So, even if class 'a' doesn't have method set(), this code still works? but is it a good coding rule?

Comment: `self` actually is a b object per se.

Comment: @avasal but I didn't get an attribute error

Comment: You see how you are passing a `b` object? You get: `b` calls `set2`, but it doesn't have one so `a`'s `set2` is called, but do you notice how `set2` calls `set`? Using `self.set(value)`. And since `self` is of type `b`, it's naturally to call `b`'s `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `self.set(value)`, it always gives you the same definition for `set()` no matter where you call it.

```
class Animal(object):
    def interact(self):
        print('I am a {}, I say "{}"'.format(self.name(), self.speak()))

class Dog(Animal):
    def name(self):
        return 'dog'
    def speak(self):
        return 'woof'
```

If you want, you can call `a.set()` explicitly.

```
class A(object):
    def set(self, value):
        print(value + 1)
    def set2(self, value):
        A.set(self, value)
```

This is a bit silly, however.  The example is so abstract you can't use it to figure out good coding style.

Answer (score 3):

You're overriding `set()` in the derived class, so that's what is getting called by `self.set()`.

To call the `a`'s method, you can use the following syntax:

```
    a.set(self, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you want to get the `a`'s `set()` to be called you need to use the following syntax.  `a().set(10)`